# What should I do when Windows Boot Manager comes instead of GRUB, even after boot repair?

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I know that this question has been asked before, but none of the solutions have solved my problem.

Ubuntu boots and runs properly with the USB I used to install it plugged in to the computer, but when I shut down, remove the USB, and reboot, Windows Boot Manager appears. I am very confused why my computer wants anything to do with Windows because I chose to wipe my drive when installing Ubunbu.

I have tried using Boot-Repair, but Windows Boot Manager still launched when I restarted without the USB. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11869251/) is the log from Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Plug the USB and boot Ubuntu from HDD.

Unplug the USB.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall grub-common grub-pc-bin grub-pc grub2-common
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install  /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
reboot
```

Comment: When I remove the USB, I can't open any applications. After that, it totally freezes. Does this mean more than just the boot loader is on the USB?

Comment: The system is running from USB not from HDD.

Comment: How would I install it to the hdd? When I plugged in the USB, I went through the regular install process. How would I install to the HDD

Comment: Goto http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: Would it help(while trying to reinstall it) to do the "try Ubuntu"?